# Forgot to acidify tomato sauce

Tags: canning, tomatoes, acid

I have 6 pint jars of tomato meat sauce, which includes shredded carrots, onions and ground pork sausage. I forgot to add citric acid this time around, but did process at 11psi for 60 minutes.

Is there any danger to consuming the tomato sauce considering the processing time as well as additional ingredients?

Comment: How recently did you make it?  It you just did it today, consider moving them to the fridge and consuming them soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe okay. This recipe from a very reputable source, does not have any added acid, vinegar or lemon juice.
https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_03/spaghetti_sauce_meat.html

From the same source:

> The bacteria that cause botulism poisoning can grow and produce toxin in sealed jars of moist food at room temperature if the pH (measure of acidity) is above 4.6.  Vegetables, meat, fish, etc. are naturally fairly high above pH 4.6 (close to 6.0) and so pressure processes were developed for those to kill the heat-resistant spores of C. botulinum bacteria that are likely to be contaminating them.

You may want to research pressure canned tomato with meat sauce recipes from trusted sources to see if acidification is necessary.